# How do I set up a wicket quickstart to use seam-wicket CDI?

Tags: dependency-injection, seam, wicket, cdi, jboss-weld

What do I need to do to make CDI work on my wicket quickstart project? When I try to launch the Jetty server, I get an exception:

```
org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.BeanManagerUnavailableException: Failed to locate BeanManager using any of these providers: org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.DefaultJndiBeanManagerProvider(11), org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.ServletContainerJndiBeanManagerProvider(10)
at org.jboss.seam.solder.beanManager.BeanManagerLocator.getBeanManager(BeanManagerLocator.java:91)
at org.jboss.seam.wicket.SeamApplication.internalInit(SeamApplication.java:54)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:723)
...
```

I am authoring a wicket project. I don't know the first thing about Seam, Weld, or CDI; I want to learn it by incorporating it into a small project. I am following this reference documentation:

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/wicket/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/

Right now, I am swimming in a sea of alien documentation trying to find the answer. Help!

**Edit:**

The Jetty server in the wicket quickstart is created programmatically. Based on the documentation given below, I created:

`webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
   "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
   <New id="BeanManager" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
      <Arg><Ref id="webAppCtx"/></Arg> 
      <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
      <Arg>
         <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
            <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg> 
            <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
            <Arg/>
         </New>
      </Arg>
   </New>
</Configure>
```

In `web.xml`, I have added the following snippet:

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>
javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
    </resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.solder.resourceLoader.servlet.ResourceListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The following Java code is responsible for setting up the Jetty server in the quickstart environment, when Start is run:

```
    Server server = new Server();
    SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();

    // Set some timeout options to make debugging easier.
    connector.setMaxIdleTime(1000 * 60 * 60);
    connector.setSoLingerTime(-1);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    WebAppContext bb = new WebAppContext();
    bb.setServer(server);
    bb.setContextPath("/");
    bb.setWar("src/main/webapp");
    // FIXME: This doesn't seem to do anything? bb.addEventListener(new ResourceListener());
    server.addHandler(bb);

/* I don't know what this commented code does, but it doesn't fix the problem when uncommented. */
// START JMX SERVER
// MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
// MBeanContainer mBeanContainer = new MBeanContainer(mBeanServer);
// server.getContainer().addEventListener(mBeanContainer);
// mBeanContainer.start();
```

I am using jetty version 6.1.25, according to my Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 42Lines folks have published a [Wicket-CDI integration library](https://github.com/42Lines/wicket-cdi) that includes a working example project.

Several of these guys are actually Wicket committers; they write good code, and they know what they're doing.

Comment: Just Igor works at 42Lines from the Wicket team but yes, you can count him as "several" :-)

Comment: @martin-g: I think Clint has also committed a bit of code to Wicket, though perhaps he is not an officially on the Wicket team.

Answer (score 1):

In a servlet container you need to bootstrap Weld CDI yourself to make it available to Seam. The documentation states this under installation:
http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/wicket/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#wicket.installation

With a link to the relative Weld bootstrapping documentation for either Jetty 6 or 7:

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5286

It should work fine after configuring Jetty to bootstrap Weld. However please take not of the limitations of using Weld within a servlet container:
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5221

Also ensure that you have an empty (or configured) beans.xml in your WEB-INF/ directory.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the problem! I was not able to get it to run; the error message is the same. I've added some details about my configuration to the question... can you please take a look at it, and see if I've done something wrong?

Comment: @RMorrisey I've added some info about a beans.xml if you do not have this Weld may not be initializing which could be the problem. Short of this I think that you should deploy to a standalone Jetty and see if you can get it working in that environment.

Comment: No dice creating a blank beans.xml file. I discovered, finally, that there are directions for creating a maven archetype for a weld servlet project. (It doesn't appear anywhere if you click "Documentation", you have to click the "Seam 3" menu section header. Go figure.) I'll try it out, and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help, so far!

Comment: I managed to get past the initial error by borrowing pieces from the mvn servlet archetype's web.xml and pom.xml, and popping them into my wicket quickstart. Now I get a NoClassDefFoundError on JspFactory, which is referenced by the listener that I copied from the archetype's web.xml (org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener). Tomorrow night, I'll look at the Listener's code and see if I can understand how it works - it seems like I'll have to implement my own, for wicket's code?

Comment: Link to the maven archetype info: http://www.seamframework.org/Documentation/CDIQuickstartForMavenUsers
I hope this helps someone else navigate through this mess.

Comment: I'm puzzled that the seam-wicket module doesn't seem to provide an implementation. How is it supposed to work?

Comment: I found this http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/web/jetty-cdi-weld-seam-wicket.texy but it does not end well, perhaps Jetty 7 will play nicer :/

Comment: Okay, I see it says, "JNDI does not work because when attaching the BeanManager to servlet.Context, inside it works so that the JNDI prefix is context.toString(), thus the whole name is „org.mortbay.jet­ty.servlet.Con­text@1a8dfb3{_,­null}/__/Bean­Manager“". I can override the WebAppContext.toString() method in an anonymous subclass... so what is it that I'm supposed to return in order to make it work? I'm skeptical of whether that guy is right about the cause of the problem.

Comment: This looks promising: http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamWicketAndServlet
Now all I have to do is install git....

Comment: Yeah that does look promising.

Comment: I'll be away for the weekend at Otakon, so I'll have to keep trying later. =)

Comment: https://www.42lines.net/2011/11/15/integrating-cdi-into-wicket for anyone else looking for how to do Wicket 1.5 and CDI